# jhiTranslate doesn't work on html template- it shows Unknown attribute 'jhiTranslate'

Tags: jhipster

I created a module(component, html tmeplate) by myself in a jhipster project. And I imported the new module into 'app.module.ts'. when I use the translation tag 'jhiTranslate' on the html template, it shows Unknown attribute 
 'jhiTranslate'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbRaM.png)

Any suggestion what I should do to enable 'jhiTranslate' in a customized module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post your module code and add some informations about your project :
- version
- front framework (seems to be angular)

what happen when you deploy and run the app ? have you some errors in the browser console ?

I suppose you didn't import your shared-module into your new one like this :

```
imports: [
    MyAppSharedModule,
    ...
],
```

The Jhipster translation directive is store into the NgJhipsterModule.

the NgJhipsterModule is import into the shared-lib.module which is import into shared.module. Import this last could fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Avdev4j 
'jhiTranslate' is working now in the customised module after I import the 'shared.module'

Comment: Could you please mark this issue as resolved ? thanks ;)